# JFileChooser Exception at calling showOpenDialog()

Tags: java, swing, exception, jfilechooser

I have a button and if it gets clicked a file chooser should be opened...
but I always get this NullPointerException.

I read something that it could be because I am starting the dialog outside the event dis. thread, but this call EventQueue.invokeLater,calls the EDT anyways, right?

Here is the source (the else if is in an ActionListener extending class - in the actionPerformed method):

```
else if(buttonID.equals(Definition.BTN_LOAD_DF_NAME))
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public String getDescription(){
                            return "XML-File";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean accept(File f){
                            return f.isDirectory() || f.getName().endsWith(".xml") || f.getName().endsWith(".XML");
                        }
                    });

                    int state = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if(state == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        try{
                            app.loadDF(fc.getSelectedFile());
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            });
        }
```

here the stacktrace:

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthFileChooserUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showDialog(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(Unknown Source)
    at logic.FuncActionListener$1.run(FuncActionListener.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for every help!!

p.s.: look and feel (must be used):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<synth>
    <style id="backingStyle">
        <opaque value="FALSE" />
    </style>
    <bind style="backingStyle" type="region" key="Panel" />
    <style id="button">
        <!-- Shift the text one pixel when pressed -->
        <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="2" />
        <state>
            <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_normal.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />
            <font name="Dialog" size="12" />
        </state>
        <state value="PRESSED">
            <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_normal_pressed.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="button" type="region" key="Button" />
    <style id="wndBG">
        <imagePainter methode="wndBackground" path="images/cdu_bg.png" sourceInsets="1 1 1 1"></imagePainter>
    </style>
    <bind style="wndBG" type="name" key="root"></bind>
</synth>
```

Comment: You are already within the EDT when you call code inside actionPerformed, therefore the invokeLater is not required. Passing `null` should not affect your JFileChooser, but it is recommended to pass something, to make sure that your FileChooser is not lost amongst other Windows

Comment: i also passed the main JFrame to it, makes no diffrence. :(

Comment: While it is a good idea to pass the JFrame, indeed, and as I already stated, it does not make a difference for your issue. It is just better for the user experience. Your problem comes from your L&F and the way you have configured it.

Comment: i added the laf. i have no idea what could be the problem there. and i have t use it...

Comment: i tried the standard laf and it works now. so the problem is the laf. but i am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It is difficult to work with your LAF config, since we don't have the images locally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16836/discussion-between-immerhart-and-guillaume-polet)

Answer (score 0):

Try `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` instead to test it works. If it fixes the NPE, this will be a problem with the event dispatching. If not, it will be a problem with the `showOpenDialog` parent's parameter being null.

Comment: He already calls invokeLater. And when you are performing actions in actionPerformed, it is not needed to call invokeLater since you are already on the EDT.

Comment: yeah, that is not the problem... i will remove it later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on stacktrace it seems that there can be something wrong in Look and Feel you use (Synth). I would try a different LaF first.
And it is recommended to always pass parent window (or any parent component) to JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(). Otherwise weird things may sometimes happen in some systems and environments (eg. the dialog is displayed behind main window, on different display or even outside desktop area).

Comment: i am using a own look and feel. but i tried it by passing the main JFrame as parameter, it does not work too!
do i have to adjust something on the look and feel?

Comment: @immerhart _I am using my own look and feel_ I would start there. It is likely a problem in the configuration of Synth.

Comment: Just try using another LaF. And I would also suggest using JDK for development so that you can get the line numbers in stacktrace and browse Synth code.